# How to upload pictures with paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Iam using rails 4.2 .... I installed paperclip gem , configured it properly but whenever I upload any picture I get 'connection was reset' by browser and in the terminal here is what i get :

```
begin transaction
Command :: file -b --mime "C:/Users/hol~1/AppData/Local/Temp/795eb2377370d89bc93f7f30ac4c055020180208-7336-1o5t9vu.png"
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename cat-1285634_640.png (image/png from Headers, ["image/png"] from Extension), content type discovered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
```

My post Model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
    has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: ""
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
    validates_length_of :description, :minimum => 15
      end
```

Comment: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/prevent-spoofing-with-paperclip

Comment: I already visited this page ages ago D:

Comment: then: is your pic really a picture? how come paperclip thinks its a spoof?

Comment: yes it is PNG also i tried plenty of others but no use